# USB 2.0 device is not working in USB 3.0 ports

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, usb

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 system. On that system I have one USB 3.0 port. In this port I am trying use my USB 2.0 device, but every time when I plug in that USB 2.0 device into the USB 3.0 port, the system gets hung and  I try to shutdown but it won't allow me to.

If I continue to match Port types to Device speeds (2.0 to 2.0) everything woks fine.

So my question is: How can I allow a USB 3.0 port to use a USB 2.0 device or is there any way to convert a USB 3.0 port to a USB 2.0 port like drivers or something?

Am I mistaking the issue I'm having for another type of problem?

Here is my `lsub` command output

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 046d:0823 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 5555:1110 Epiphan Systems Inc. VGA2USB
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0d8c:0008 C-Media Electronics, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

and for `dmesg` command output you can refer this [link](http://pastebin.com/vfu7gLkX)

Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the relevant output lines of `dmesg` after plugging-in the device?

Comment: @AndreasWiese I have added dmesg command output. can you look into it.

Comment: @AndreasWiese I have added updated dmesg command output can you please look into it and let me suggestions on it.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of dmesg output to the question so it's not lost if the external stops working.

Comment: What is the hardware that you're using here? Is it a laptop? If so can you give us the specific model number etc?

Comment: This sounds related to your issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090382. The only way to confirm would be to upgrade your kernel or distro though.

Comment: Does it work if you plugin USB3 drive? I think the problem might be that your USB3 controller is not supported by the kernel.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457901/usb-2-0-device-scanner-does-not-work-with-xhci-hcd-on-usb-3-0-system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is retalted to the kernel. I have the same type of problem. To resovle this issue I updated my kernel. For this I reffred this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel)

Comment: Updated your kernel to what, exactly?  Here I am two years after your post with the same problem and kernel 4.1.26.  I will guess your kernel is older, but I might be wrong.